# File system operations through UAC fail until I use file explorer

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, filesystems, uac

In Visual Studio, I have a package project referencing a uwp and a .NET 4.8 program.

The uwp app and the .NET framework program communicate via desktop bridge.

The manifest of the package declares the full trust capability.

The uwp app sends file system operations requests to the .NET program.
These requests ask to perform operations like copy, move,delete or rename files and folders.

When performing operations on protected locations like the root of a hard drive, a windows dialog 'file access denied' asks user's permission.

Upon clicking yes, the uac dialog appears to ask for permission.
Then, if I click yes in the dialog, nothing happens.

But if I then perform some similar operation on the same location with Windows' file explorer, and give my consent to the windows dialog it works without any uac prompt.

Then, I can return to my app, and when trying some file system operation, the same uac dialog appears, but the operation is successful every time.

The described behavior is the same regardless of the method used by the .NET framework (`System.IO`, `VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSytem`, various wrappers for `SHFileoperation` or `IFileoperation`, `cmd.exe`, Powershell, etc...)

To summarize, I need to use Windows' file explorer once, and then uac will let my app perform file system operations. The app should work without this workaround.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: Have you declared `broadFileSystemAccess` and turned-on File Permissions in App Settings?

Comment: Yes, I did declare broadfFileSystemAccess. In windows, when I go to Settings>Apps and features, click my app  and select advanced options, the only app premission I see is background apps. Is it the menu you are refering to?

Comment: No, after you declared [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example), **File system** should be under the **App permissions** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysxsD.png

Comment: According to copilot, the reason I don't see it is because I have not enabled the file system access for my app in the Windows settings.
But if I go to to Settings > Privacy > File system, under 'choose which apps can access your file system', I don't see any app name.
Do you think it could be related? Copilot suggested this with powershell :  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} but it didn't help

Comment: According to your situation, “ I have a package project referencing a uwp and a .NET 4.8 program.” Why not perform file operations in the .NET 4.8 program?

Comment: It is the case, that's the reason why the .net 4.8 program and the fulltrust capability were added.  The strange thing is that after doing one admin operation with windows's file eplorer, my app can succesfuly go through uac.

Comment: I may misunderstand your scenario, so let's go back to the beginning. Why are you using fulltrust? Do you want to use desktop bridge to call other win32 APIs in UWP? Or just need file operations?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Fulltrust is used to launch the .net program. Uwp and .net 4.8 communicate together with desktop bridge. Among other things, the .net 4.8 perform file system operations, hence the broadFileSystemAccess capability. I am in the process of upgrading the .net 4.8 to .net 8.0, hoping it will have a more effective treatment by uac.